# Missing scaled resolution for external 4K display on MacBook 2016

Tags: macos, display, resolution

I'm running my MacBook 2016 attached to LG 27MU67-B operating fine in native 4K resolution. But the choices for scaled (DPI)resolution are somewhat broken.

In display preferences pane I'm presented scaled resolution setting choices as follows:

- 3840 x 2160
- 1920 x 1080
- 1680 x 945
- and more useless resolutions.

I'm currently forced to use 1920x1080 which results on a ridiculously zoomed in UI. The highest resolution is native resolution which is a bit too small to work with. With a MacBookPro 2012 I get a 2400-something resolution, which is not available on the MacBook. Is this limit imposed by the MacBook hardware ? Or is it possible to activate more higher resolutions than 1920x1080 but lower than 3840 x 2160 with a `defaults write` trick ?

This is a screenshot of my currently possible settings:

[image]

Comment: I read somewhere online (don't have a source) that 10.12.1 fixed this for some people. Can you comment on that?

Comment: Nope. I can not really comment on the old setup, since I returned the HDMI Dongle and switched to another brand (Anker). 10.12.1 was released before I had the new dongle. But now I have 2560x1440 available plus some more. So maybe yes 10.12.1 fixes this issue, maybe no.

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful to know that the adapter can be a limitation

Comment: Well even that is not known. Maybe the old adaptor is running better with 10.12.1... It was already returned before I upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

Select the highest resolution and then alt-click the *Scaled* radio-button. You can then select scaling of the UI:
[image]

Comment: I switched to the drop down list of scaled resolutions to illustrate my choices. Switching back to _simple selection mode_ does not change the outcome. It is still 3840x2160 or 1920x1080 and nothing in-between.

Comment: It is not a simple selection mode but rather a scaling of the UI that uses the selected resolution. So you can use the highest resolution without having to look at microscopic UI elements.

Comment: I am aware of that. I'm running the native 4k resolution suitable for the monitor.  But I don't get the choice for specific scaled UI (More Space) resolutions. Please re-read the question if you care.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for my 2016 MacBook and most of the solution I found on Google didn't work except this third party application which enables hidden ratina resolutions.

Application - http://avi.alkalay.net/software/RDM/
GitHub Project - https://github.com/avibrazil/RDM

Answer (score 0):

I'm on MacOS 14.1 Sonoma
Facing same issue.I got a LG 4K HRD monitorand found when I set to 4K, UI is very small. scaling option is missing.but HDR is OK

Actually it's OK to use 1080p since it's 4k looks like 1080p

I made a video to explain it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-InKgOHzs4